# How to carry over autogenerated GUID onto another page after creating one

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am currently doing a sign-up page and i would like to insert data ( 1 page for 1 table )
After inserting data into the first table and generating the uid, i would like to bring over the generated uid to the next page.I tried to bring over the userid with viewbag on the textbox on the next page. However i end up with 0000-0000-0000-0000 instead. Can i seek some help?
My references are below.

```
       [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAccounts(UserDTO userDto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.message = "Form is invalid please check again.";
            return View("~/Views/Login/Register.cshtml");
        }
        string url = BaseUrl + "/User/Dto/" + "Create";
        UserModel recievedUserModel = new UserModel();

        #region Salting and hashing
        byte[] salt = new byte[128 / 8];
        using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
        {
            rng.GetBytes(salt);
        }

        // derive a 256-bit subkey (use HMACSHA1 with 10,000 iterations)
        string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
            password: userDto.Password,
            salt: salt,
            prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA256,
            iterationCount: 10000,
            numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
        #endregion

        userDto.Salt = salt;
        userDto.Password = hashed;

        StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userDto), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
            string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                recievedUserModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserModel>(apiResponse);
                ViewBag.message = userDto.UserID;
            }
            else if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                ViewBag.message = apiResponse;
            }
        }
        return View("~/Views/Login/Register2.cshtml");
    }

   [HttpPost("Dto/Create")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUserFromUserDto(UserDTO userDto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }



        UserModel userModel = new UserModel();

        if (!_context.User.Any(u => u.Username.Equals(userDto.Username)))
        {
            userModel = new UserModel()
            {
                AccessLevel = userDto.AccessLevel,
                Username = userDto.Username,
                Password = userDto.Password,
                Salt = userDto.Salt,
                Surname = userDto.Surname,
                GivenName = userDto.GivenName,
                ContactNo = userDto.ContactNo,
                Gender = userDto.Gender,
                Email = userDto.Email,
                YearOfBirth = userDto.YearOfBirth
            };
            try
            {
                _context.User.Add(userModel);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Ok();
            }
            catch
            {
                return BadRequest("Unable to save to database.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest("Username exists, try a different username.");
        }
    }
```

Here is my HTML code

```
@model TTSH_ALIVE.DTOs.UserDTO
@using TTSH_ALIVE.ModelObjects

@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
Layout = null; }
<head>
<title>Welcome - TTSH SteWARdS</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/images/icons/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/fonts/Linearicons-Free-v1.0.0/icon-font.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/vendor/animate/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/util.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/main.css">
</head>

<div class="limiter">
<div class="container-login100">
    <div class="wrap-login100 p-t-50 p-b-0">
        <span class="login100-form-error p-t-20 p-b-45">
            @ViewBag.error
        </span>
        <div class="jp-container" style="margin-top:20px">
            <h1 class="jp-jumbo"><b>Sign Up</b></h1>
            <hr style="width:80px; border:5px solid #a6192e" class="jp-round">
        </div>

        <div class="jp-row">
            <form asp-action="CreateAccounts">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                @*<div class="form-group">
                      <label asp-for="UserID" class="control-label"></label>
                      <input asp-for="UserID" class="form-control" />
                      <span asp-validation-for="UserID" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>*@
                <div class="form-group-full">
                    <label asp-for="Username" class="text-white"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-white"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group-full">
                    <label asp-for="Password" class="text-white"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" type="password" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-white"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group-half">
                    <label asp-for="GivenName" class="text-white"></label>
                    <input asp-for="GivenName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="GivenName" class="text-white"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group-half">
                    <label asp-for="Surname" class="text-white"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Surname" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Surname" class="text-white"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group-full">
                    <label asp-for="Gender" class="text-white"></label><br />
                    <select asp-for="Gender" class="jp-select">
                        <option selected disabled>---Please select a gender---</option>
                        <option>Male</option>
                        <option>Female</option>
                        <option>Others</option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Gender" class="text-white"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group-full">
                    <label asp-for="ContactNo" class="text-white"></label>
                    <input asp-for="ContactNo" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="ContactNo" class="text-white"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group-full">
                    <label asp-for="Email" class="text-white"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-white"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group-full">
                    <label asp-for="YearOfBirth" class="text-white"></label>
                    <input asp-for="YearOfBirth" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="YearOfBirth" class="text-white"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="text-white">
                    <b>@ViewBag.message</b>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group-half">
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="jp-btn-86" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group-half">
                    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Login" asp-action="Index" style="margin-top: 7px" class="login100-form-btn">Back to Login</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

2nd page

```
@model TTSH_ALIVE.Models.Dependent
@using TTSH_ALIVE.ModelObjects

@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
Layout = null; }
<head>
<title>Welcome - TTSH SteWARdS</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/images/icons/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/fonts/Linearicons-Free-v1.0.0/icon-font.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/vendor/animate/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/util.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/main.css">
</head>

<div class="limiter">
<div class="container-login100">
    <div class="wrap-login100 p-t-50 p-b-0">
        <span class="login100-form-error p-t-20 p-b-45">
            @ViewBag.error
        </span>
        <div class="jp-container" style="margin-top:20px">
            <h1 class="jp-jumbo"><b>Sign Up</b></h1>
            <hr style="width:80px; border:5px solid #a6192e" class="jp-round">
        </div>

        <div class="jp-row">
            <form asp-action="CreateAccounts">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group-full">
                    <label asp-for="UserID" class="text-white"></label>
                    <input asp-for="UserID" value="@ViewBag.message" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="UserID" class="text-white"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group-half">
                    <label asp-for="AgeOfDependent" class="text-white"></label>
                    <input asp-for="AgeOfDependent" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="AgeOfDependent" class="text-white"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group-half">
                    <label asp-for="DependentType" class="text-white"></label>
                    <input asp-for="DependentType" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="DependentType" class="text-white"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="text-white">
                    <b>@ViewBag.message</b>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group-half">
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="jp-btn-86" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group-half">
                    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Login" asp-action="Index" style="margin-top: 7px" class="login100-form-btn">Back to Login</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: Where does this guid get generated exactly? By the way, it wont work with ViewBag, because the viewbag doesnt work both ways, it can only go from server to client, not the other way around

Comment: hi sir, @nalnpir. i tried the viewbag on other attribute such as username and it returns me the username. just that i want the uid instead and i am unsure on how to solve it